# How can I make this blocky surface smooth?

Tags: smooth

In the attached pic, I need to make the highlighted areas smooth and spherical.  If you look at the top plane of the object, the vertices are arranged in a perfect circle, which I what I want.  I've tried to use the Shift-Alt-S, or Transform to Sphere, but it doesn't seem to work on a partial circle.  How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you remove this part and extrude down the half circle?

Comment: Suggestion. Delete the highlighted area, keeping the well formed partial circle edge.  Select the edge of well formed partial circle edge and extrude down on Z axis.  If you are unfamiliar with that terminology, the famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob can help.

Comment: Great suggestions, and I was working on doing exactly that.  My problem is that rather long-ish face directly to the right of the highlighted area.  I need to cut that off right at the level of the bottom of the selected area, and I haven't yet been able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out!  I just had to select all the vertices that would make up what I wanted the new face to look like and press F, and then delete the old face.